# Repeating code in programm which working with register

Tags: c#

I have a working program with correct code, hovewer, I would like to improve my code. A string "AlternateCharCases((char[])word.Clone(), startIndex + 1, result);" is repeated twice. How can I escape this repeating? Because it's impossible in my situation.

```
public class CaseAlternatorTask
{
   const string checkingSymbols = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

   public static List<string> AlternateCharCases(string lowercaseWord)
   {
       var result = new List<string>();
       AlternateCharCases(lowercaseWord.ToCharArray(), 0, result);
       return result;   
   }

   static void AlternateCharCases(char[] word, int startIndex, List<string> result)
   {
       if (word.Length == startIndex)
       {
           result.Add(new string(word));
           return;
       }
       if (checkingSymbols.Contains(word[startIndex]))
       {
          AlternateCharCases((char[])word.Clone(), startIndex + 1, result);
          word[startIndex] = char.ToUpper(word[startIndex]);    
       }
       AlternateCharCases((char[])word.Clone(), startIndex + 1, result);
    } 
}
```

Comment: `AlternateCharCases` is function is not a string. First of all, tell us what are you trying to achieve. We don't know what does mean **improve** your code

Comment: Improving code means rewriting it so that AlternateCharCases does not repeat

Comment: Do you understand that it will behave differently?